# Using CMake to generate Visual Studio 2015 Makefile Project (GDB)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, gdb, cross-platform

Visual Studio 2015 introduce new remote debugging capabilities using GDB which can be very useful for who ever use CMake to build his project on a Linux machine.
These capabilities are part of the VS Makefile Project (GDB) type.

Is there a way to configure CMake to generate a Visual Studio solution with the Makefile Project (GDB) type instead of the regular C++ project type?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: From the search i did, generating such a project type is not supported yet by CMake, although it will be very useful for cross platform developers.
I did found that a patch is in progress and an [early availability can be found on this talented guy github](https://github.com/cperthuis/CMake-GDB-VS-Project-Test)

Answer (score -2):

You can try to create a new GDB project in VS http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/cmake/